# T-SQL - How to convert SELECT statements stored in table cells to a result?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have a table that has 2 columns. The first is an ID and the second is a SQL SELECT statement related to that ID. What I need is some function or procedure that can parse every row and turn each SELECT statement into an output.

I am using MS SQL Server 2016

Example
Table Name: Test

```
|-----------|---------------------------------------------------------- |
|     ID    |                           SQL                             |
|-----------|-----------------------------------------------------------|
|      1    | SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.Example WHERE SomeFilter = 'A'   |
|-----------|-----------------------------------------------------------|
|      2    | SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.Example WHERE SomeFilter = 'B'   |
|-----------|-----------------------------------------------------------|
```

I can get a single result per line using code below but I am looking for a procedure that can process the whole table and output a result for every entry

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SQL = (SELECT [SQL] FROM [dbo].[Test])
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL
```

Desired output

```
|-----------|---------------------------------------------------------- |--------------|
|     ID    |                           SQL                             |     Output   |
|-----------|-----------------------------------------------------------|--------------|
|      1    | SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.Example WHERE SomeFilter = 'A'   |              |
|-----------|-----------------------------------------------------------|--------------|
|      2    | SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.Example WHERE SomeFilter = 'B'   |              |
|-----------|-----------------------------------------------------------|--------------|
```

Is something like this possible?
If yes - any assistance showing the steps would be appreciated. As mentioned I can get a line by line ad-hoc result per row but need an automated method to parse the whole table and return an extra column with results of each SQL query.

Thanks

Comment: You can do this in a stored procedure using dynamic SQL and a looping mechanism.

Comment: You could write own `EVAL` function for SQL Server using CLR.

Comment: Sample implemenation using PostgreSQL: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=f683804ca709c4e6687150771813d07d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple looping mechanism as mentioned by Gordon.

```
DECLARE @ID INT = 1
DECLARE @MAXID INT = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM dbo.Test)
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

CREATE TABLE #TMP (count_records INT, id_from_source INT)

WHILE @ID <= @MAXID 
BEGIN
    SELECT @SQL = (SELECT SQL FROM Test WHERE ID = @ID)
    IF @SQL IS NOT NULL 
    BEGIN
        INSERT #TMP (count_records)
        EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL
        UPDATE #TMP SET id_from_source = @ID WHERE id_from_source IS NULL
    END
    SET @ID = @ID + 1
END

SELECT * FROM #TMP
```

Comment: Thanks that provides 2 separate output values which are correct but I need an overall result where they are part of the original table and linked to the respective entry line. That is the part that I can't figure out at this point

Comment: I updated the code to include a temp table to capture your results. Please note that this will only work if the queries that you run return fields that match the temp table definition

Comment: Thanks but now it's the same issue as with the other answer. The result in temp table has the counts but I also need the 2nd column with the ID's from the source and I am stuck because I can either get the counts loaded on their own or ID columns but not both

Comment: Edited my query to add an additional column to capture the source id. Upon insertion into temp table, the id_from_source column will have a default value of NULL. We could take advantage of this condition to update this column. Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks! That seems to work. I had to move the SET @ ID = @ ID + 1 command up so that its after the UPDATE followed by END. Otherwise the query ran forever and when I stopped it there were thousands of entries.

Comment: I tried moving SET @ ID = @I D + 1 up. For the example that I am using, I noticed that IF there is a gap between successive IDs, for example, 1,2,4,5.. then only 1 and 2 will be inserted into the table and the query will run forever since @ ID is not incremented because @ SQL value will be NULL. However, I am glad I was able to help. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this is what you asked for

```
Create Procedure gen_SQL_STM
AS 
    DECLARE @stmList CURSOR;
    DECLARE @id varchar(max);
    DECLARE @sql varchar(max);
    DECLARE @counts int;

    BEGIN
        SET @stmList = CURSOR FOR
        SELECT stm.id, stm.sqlCol
        from testTable stm  

    OPEN @stmList 
    FETCH NEXT FROM @stmList 
    INTO @id, @sql
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN

        EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql= @counts OUTPUT
        INSERT INTO testTable2(id, sqlstm, MYoutput_count)
        SELECT @id, @sql, @counts
        FETCH NEXT FROM @stmList
        INTO @id, @sql 
    END; 
    CLOSE @stmList ;
    DEALLOCATE @stmList;
    END;
GO
```

Comment: I tried this and it looks promising but having an issue. I took your code and adjusted it to match the actual tables and columns on my end. When I execute it I get 3 separate results. (1) Count value from first query - Correct. (2) Count value from second query - Correct. (3) Result from new table - I see the 2 distinct ID's and SELECT queries but the Output is 0 for both

Comment: Did you try to run "select" query from testTable of the corresponding id's separately? and did they give you different results?

Comment: I think something is not right with "EXECUTE @ counts = sp_executesql @ sql OUT" - that statement outputs 2 separate numeric values on the screen during execution which are correct. However I added SELECT @ counts to the code and the result is 0 for both during the execution. So even though I see the right results separately its like they are not getting stored in the @ counts variable

Comment: Did you try it with out the "output" ?

Comment: Tried removing "OUTPUT" after @ sql on the EXECUTE line but result is same. The @ counts variable results are zeros unfortunately.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181633/discussion-between-jetrocket11-and-user4321).

Comment: Hi - updated answer didn't work. Error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'EXECUTE'. Seems that it does not allow SELECT and EXECUTE in the same statement.